# Prevent customer from double submitting order?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have an ecommerce website that uses jQuery 1.9.1 and Bootstrap 2.3.2

I'd like to prevent customers from double-submitting orders on accident (hitting submit twice).

Any ideas on how to do this?

My input submit is simply:

```
 <input type="submit" class="btn btn-orange pull-right" value="Place Order">
```

Is there anything I can do to prevent this from occurring? I don't want to hinder other customers, I just don't want folks to submit, wait, get impatient, submit again, and they are double charged for their order. That's sloppy.

Thanks.

Comment: remove the submit button on submit. Prevent further submissions via the submit event after it happens once.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a little trick:

```
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-orange pull-right" value="Place Order" onClick="this.disabled=1">
```

Comment: don't work here, did `onclick="$(this).attr('disabled', '')"`

Answer (score 0):

Disable the button when form is submitted. You can do something like this:

```
$('.pull-right').click(function() {
  // Code to submit the form
  $(this).attr('disabled', true);
});
```

This SO Question might help
[How-to-prevent-calling-of-en-event-handler-twice-on-fast-clicks](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20281546/1310070)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-orange pull-right" value="Place Order" onclick="$(this).attr('disabled', true);">
```

Comment: What if there's an error on the form when they click the submit button? Would it still be disabled? Then when they try to submit again, it won't let them? Is there anything I can do about that?

Comment: You can enable the button if the form has an error. I cannot help you with that, unless you give us more informations about your form, and what you use to post the form values.

Comment: @user1879703 This is a pretty nice use case you have come up with.Look at my answer. I think you can use that to enable the button back when youor network request is complete either success/failed.

Comment: @ahmadalbayati Interesting, I just tried that and my form didn't even try to submit or go through validation. 

My test page is at: (put something into cart => go to cart => checkout)
https://rsatestamle.dminsite.com:444/checkout.aspx?

Interesting. Not sure what's keeping it from running validation or submission.

Comment: Try putting `$(this).attr('disabled', true);` in the beginning of the code that submits the form values

Comment: You have given us too little information to work on. I think i know what's wrong, but it's hard to help if you don't tell us more. If you are using javascript to submit your form, you can just put `$(this).attr('disabled', true);` in the beginning of the function that runs onSubmit, or onClick. Otherwise, you should you use my answer or @Goran. it's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Some times you may want to also run a function like: OnSubmit function (or a **validation**) you can do this:

```
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-orange pull-right" value="Place Order" onclick="this.disabled=true;OnSubmit(this.parentNode);" />
```