# disabling a button while running a function

Tags: javascript

I have a function in Javascript which is called by clicking a button and it takes approximately one minute to be finished. How can I disable the button after one click and enable it again after function is finished?
I need this process to prevent spamming.

I tried the following piece of code, but it is not working. It is still possible to click the button several times.

Javascript:

```
function myFunc()
{
    document.getElementById("Btn").disabled = true;
    \\do something for one minute
    document.getElementById("Btn").disabled = false;
}
```

html:

```
 <button type="button" id="Btn" onclick="myFunc()">Generate!</button>
```

Comment: I assume _\\do something for one minute_ is some async task, hence `*.disabled = false;` could be placed in the `callback`.

Comment: *do something for one minute* <- Maybe you are doing async process?

Comment: check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20281546/how-to-prevent-calling-of-en-event-handler-twice-on-fast-clicks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is working fine. Maybe your function runs quickly that's why it appears as you can spam.

If you're calling function thru ajax, make sure `async` is `false` (default is `true`)

```js
function myFunc() {
  document.getElementById("Btn").disabled = true;
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('hey');
    document.getElementById("Btn").disabled = false;
  }, 1000);

}
```

```html
<button type="button" id="Btn" onclick="myFunc()">Generate!</button>
```